# Is it possible to pass parameters to a fixture?

Tags: python, pytest

I am not talking about the "Fixture Parametrizing" as defined by pytest, I am talking about real parameters that you pass to a function (the fixture function in this case) to make code more modular.

To demonstrate, this is my fixture

```
@yield_fixture
def a_fixture(a_dependency):
    do_setup_work()
    yield
    do_teardown_work()
    a_dependency.teardown()
```

As you see, my fixture depends on `a_dependency` whose teardown() needs to be called as well. I know in the naive use-case, I could do this:

```
@yield_fixture
def a_dependency():
    yield
    teardown()

@yield_fixture
def a_fixture(a_dependency):
    do_setup_work()
    yield
    do_teardown_work()
```

However, while the `a_fixture` code can be put in a central place and re-used by all tests, the `a_dependecy` code is test-specific and each test possibly needs to create a new `a_dependency` object.

I want to avoid copy-pasting both fixture and dependency to all my tests. If this was regular python code, I could just pass the `a_dependecy` as a function argument. How can I pass this object to my shared fixture?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me like maybe you don't want `a_dependency` to be a fixture, you just want it to be a regular function. Are you after something like this?

```
def a_dependency():
    # returns a context manager


@yield_fixture
def a_fixture():
    with a_dependency() as dependency:
        do_setup_work()
        yield
        do_teardown_work()
```

Comment: This would work, however the `a_dependency` *is* a ficture and I need its fixture capabilities (setting the `scope="class"` for instance)

Answer (score 0):

OK, well if `a_dependency` really has to be a fixture, why not the best of both worlds? Decorators are just syntactic sugar after all.

```
def a_dependency():
    # returns a context manager

a_dependency_fixture = yield_fixture(a_dependency)


@yield_fixture
def a_fixture():
    # here use a_dependency as a regular function
    with a_dependency() as dependency:
        do_setup_work()
        yield
        do_teardown_work()



def test_foo(a_dependency_fixture):
    # here use a_dependency as a fixture
    pass
```

I haven't checked that this actually works because the information in the question is too generic for me to make a working case out of. It may be easier to give a more useful answer if you can provide more specifics.